# Create Fillable PDF Textbox via R

Tags: r, pdf, markdown

I am using the test file from R Markdown, generated in RStudio by simple creating a new markdown file. It appears as follows:

````
---
title: "Fillable Textbox?"
author: "The Need To Edit"
date: "Wednesday, October 21, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

  This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

**My Question:**

> Is it possible to create a fillable textbox within the PDF form?

I am working to automate some of my workflow however within that automation the end user may need to add comments. I thought a fillable textbox would be a nice way to maintain a standard document format and give my users some freedom. I have found ways to do nearly everything except add a fillable textbox, perhaps I am searching the wrong expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hyperref package (which is loaded automatically) allows fillable fields. It is just a matter of use its specific commands, which you can find [here](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-200006). Try this code (click on the right of the word `Name`).

````
---
title: "Fillable Textbox?"
author: "The Need To Edit"
date: "Wednesday, October 21, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

Since Rmarkdown uses knitr and it loads automatically hyperref I think hat this should work.

In fact it is just a matter of use some \LaTeX\ commands of the hyperref package.

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```


\begin{Form}
    \TextField{Name}
\end{Form}
````

Of course this PDF is fillable as a PDF, and then it will not work inside the RStudio (if you use it) PDF viewer.

Comment: This is what I was after, thanks. Strange that this documentation didn't pop up in my searches. Regardless this will save many hours! Cheers.

Comment: If this is external of the scope I'll ask a new question (others may wonder anyhow) I wish to change the size of the text box and allow it to expand when exceeded. I have attempted to declare the `TextField` parameters as well as call `\MakeTextField{width}{height}` filling with units in inches (attempted pixels as well,  did not declare a unit) and received the lovely Status 43. As I said I'll gladly open a new thread if to far off base.

Comment: hmmm strange. @HoneyDippedBadger Try to open with Adobe Reader, if it still does not work, try these options `\TextField[width = Xcm, height = Xcm]{Label:}` where `X` is a number.

Comment: Excellent, that generates a nice large text box. It was the unit declaration, I didn't notice it in the documentation and took R for granted. Now to decipher text wrapping and text box expansion! (I'll ask new questions if I can't sort those out) Thank you very much for your quick response!