# Creating a fillable and colored textbox in R Markdown (PDF)

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a markdown, where the text that accompanies the plots and tables are in dark blue boxes, like the image down below:
[image]

I've tried looking at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269484/create-fillable-pdf-textbox-via-r), but I wasn't able to reproduce the box at all, and certainly not in a colored version. Does anyone have a good idea on how to do this in markdown?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Test"
date: "22/6/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\begin{Form}
    \TextField[width = 10cm, height = 10cm]{This is the textbox.}
    I would like a dark blue textbox with white writing
\end{Form}
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\TextField` command takes some optional arguments to define color and default text:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

\begin{Form}
    \TextField[width = 10cm,%
               height = 3cm,%
               multiline=true,%
               bordercolor = 0 0 0.5,%
               backgroundcolor = 0 0 0.5,%
               color = 1 1 1,%
               value = {%
                          This is the textbox.
                          I would like a dark blue textbox with white writing
                        }%
               ]{}
\end{Form}
```

This produces:

[image]

One can edit the `\TextField` to contain multi-line text, but I am not able to set a `value` with multiple lines. Using `\string\n` (c.f. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416218/how-to-add-line-breaks-to-hyperref-pdf-form-textfield) does not work for me. This might depend on the PDF viewer, though. I am using Evince.

Comment: I can't get the colors to work though - it's just black/white with me. Do you have any idea where I can find more information about this?

Comment: @Nordsted Interesting. Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: I use Adobe, but isn't there a trick to have the same outcome regardless of PDF viewer? I thought the whole idea of a PDF was that it would be the same outcome regardless of software.

Comment: @Nordsted I think there have always been things that not every pdf viewer supports. I am surprised however that Acrobat Reader does not support this. Do you feel comfortable with building a LaTeX based mcve? I think the experts for this are over at tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'll try and post a question there. I hope I won't be slaughtered - as you can see from my question, I'm not an expert at all, when it comes to LaTeX :-D

Comment: @Nordsted If you start from the tex file generated by above Rmd file and remove *everyting* that is not necessary to reproduce the issue (which should be quite a lot), you should be fine. You can reference thisquestion for context.