# Create editable field/form in pdf from R

Tags: r, pdf

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a pdf file from R that is then has editable fields/is a form which can be filled in by the user (eg in Acrobat Reader)

I found this post which does it using Rmarkdown:

[Create Fillable PDF Textbox via R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269484/create-fillable-pdf-textbox-via-r)

However, I would like to do it from base R. This is for two main reasons:

- I already have a script in R thats working so don't want to change to Rmarkdown, and
- The current script is making quite a lot of individual pdfs and it is impractical to split the script into many many Rmarkdowns and (as far as I know) an R Markdown can only make 1 pdf file and I need lots of different ones

Comment: Scrolling (not really reading) through the accepted accepted answer makes me think that this functionality is provided by LaTeX (and not markdown _per se_). Technically this would be possible in R, but that would probably be its own endeavor (but I really don't know enough about this, so I may be totally off).

Comment: Hi Sarah. How are you creating the pdfs at the moment if you're not using R Markdown? Are you doing graphics-only pdfs?

Comment: An r script could knit rmarkdown with a loop. The rmarkdown could source another existing r script. Is that worth thinking about?

Comment: @AllanCameron yeah they are mainly graphs created in ggplot or similar but they have captions or figure titles and some of these would be very useful if they could be customisable by end users (who aren't coders)

Comment: @Sarah in that case, you will really need to look at creating the pdfs using a method like Rmarkdown. Effectively what you're doing at the moment is just printing a picture as a pdf.

Comment: @AllanCameron its not exactly printing a picture as a pdf though, because the text retains the ability to be copied and pasted and you can search in the pdf that is created for strings in heading etc.. But it does seem like Rmarkdown might be the main option