# R for making interactive PDF documents?

Tags: r, pdf, interactive

I need to make a PDF document with multiple fillable forms and these forms are somewhat smart as their inputs are used for calculating the outputs of other fields. Can we use R for such a purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use RMarkdown and Latex for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269484/create-fillable-pdf-textbox-via-r) for creating forms withing RMarkdown. And [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75981/pdftex-and-javascript-forms-with-automatic-calculations) for how to do calculations in pdf forms with Latex.

Since most of the work will be done in Latex you could just skip the RMarkdown part and do it in Latex only.